Is it possible to make ng-content select="..." to work with another ng-content projection?
I have a library component app-internal, it uses content projection with some selectors - here it is h1 and h2. No I want to create decorator wrapper for that component - PublicCompoent that is supposed to project down its content to InternalComponent. However, it does not work if InternalComponent is using <ng-content select="...">. Is it possible to make it work after all assuming that I cannot modify app-internal component?
It is crucial that want to accept content of PublicComponent as input to InternalComponent.
Example:
//internal component:

  <div class="internal">
<!--this works -->
    <ng-content></ng-content>

    <ng-content select="h2"></ng-content> <!--this does not work -->
    <ng-content select="h1"></ng-content> <!--this does not work -->
  </div>

//wrapper component
<div class="public">

    WRAPPING START
    <app-internal>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </app-internal>
    WRAPPING END
  </div>

//how I would like to actually be able to use it
  <app-public>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <h2>there</h2>
  </app-public>

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-17-starter-project-al4ddu?file=src%2Fmain.ts

You can just create a h1 and h2 as a proxy to transmit the data to the inner component, this approach is very basic, but is a possible solution to overcome that the tags are not understood when it is deeply sent through content projection!
We need to apply some CSS to make it seem like the component is a plain div and not its own element!
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-internal',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
  <div class="internal">
<!--this works -->
    <!-- <ng-content></ng-content> -->

    <ng-content select="h2"></ng-content> 
    <ng-content select="h1"></ng-content> 
  </div>`,
})
export class InternalComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-public',
  standalone: true,
  template: `<div class="public">
    WRAPPING START
    <app-internal>
      <h1 style="margin: 0px !important;"><ng-content select="h1"></ng-content></h1>
      <h2 style="margin: 0px !important;"><ng-content select="h2"></ng-content></h2>
    </app-internal>
    WRAPPING END
  </div>`,
  imports: [InternalComponent],
})
export class PublicComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
  <app-public>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <h2>there</h2>
  </app-public>
  `,
  imports: [PublicComponent],
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}
bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

The thing is that you have to be able to pass down original element as is - consider custom angular component as content for example. Consider h* not to be headers but arbitrary element.

@Antoniossss it's not possible as far as I know, is it ok to modify the source library app-internal we can use content child to do something

This is what I have been told as well.  Its kind of sad that ng-content acutally do the trick, the only problem are selectors. I guess i will have to do more straightforward, less elastic wrappers ;/
